# StackApplet Faenza icons

Tags: icons, stackapplet

StackApplet icons do not match Faenza icon set (system tray icons). Was wondering if there are any better icons out there.

Links are welcome.

I am also looking for Pithos icons (size 22 for the system tray as well).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking two questions here - please ask the second question (That is, a Pithos icon) in a second question - AskUbuntu works best when there is only one question per post. :)

Comment: I am the author of StackApplet and would more than welcome additional icons that more closely match a theme. Hopefully you've already tried the lighter icon (which can be enabled through the preferences page).

Comment: @George: thanks for your work, man. Did not mean to say anything wrong about your icons, but they just do not match what I have, or at least, what I want to have. I made my own icons for both light and dark Faenza themes -- will upload them in the self-response to my question below.

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: @George: Have posted them with some screenshots below. I made the ones for the light theme before I switched to the dark Faenza theme, so they are different. But I really like how my dark-icons look like. Feel free to use them in your great app, and if you want you may refer to this post or simply to Vadim (vcherep) and askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first, the icons I have made. And then I will show how I install them now.

I am using the dark theme right now, so the icons for the light theme are my first try and they are quite different from what I have for the dark theme.

The StackApplet icons have two states: off (no new messages) and on (there are new messages).

---

For Faenza Light Theme:

- This is how it looked before and looks now (off and on):

  [image]

  [image]

  [image]
- This is not precisely consistent with the Faenza theme as the theme uses "flat grey" to indicate that there is no messages and "3D grey" to indicate that there are messages. I used colors to indicate new messages. Also, the image itself is neither exactly the stackoverflow nor stackexchange icon, something in between. As I said I do not use these icons now, so did not change anything.
- The icons:

  - stackapplet.png: [image]
  - stackapplet_grey.png: [image]

---

For Faenza Dark Theme (I use these now):

- This is how it looks now (off and on):

  [image]

  [image]
- The icons (you may not see the second one, but believe me it is there :), and installed it looks exactly as shown above):

  - stackapplet.png: [image]
  - stackapplet_grey.png: [image]

---

To install the icons I put them in one folder and also the following script in the same folder:

**note that this will delete the original icons, so that you might want to back up them first**

```
#!/bin/bash --
sudo cp -f stackapplet.png /usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet.png
sudo cp -f stackapplet_grey.png /usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet_grey.png
```

Comment: Yeah, the only thing I wanted to mention is that they are 24px vertically, and the panel may shrink them by 2 pixels, so you need to delete the first and the last row in every image if that happens (make them 22px high).